# Testing on real devices

Tags: android, android-emulator

We have recently bought ~20 different Android phones for testing (the emulators/online services just aren't good enough). When the phones are connected all at the same time the driver detects around half of them, but if I connect them one by one all are detected.

Is that a problem with the USB driver? Are there any alternative ways of doing this? I know that it is possible to run adb connect 
[IP]:[PORT] but it seems like you need to root the phones for that.

Comment: There may be a maximum number of devices that ADB can keep track of at once.

When you connected them one by one, were you disconnecting the previous device?

Comment: no, just adding new ones

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking for a different means to get your apk onto your devices. I find myself testing on a similar number of devices, what I've gone to most recently is drop the apk inside dropbox and copy a link to it, then generate a QR that points to that link. Then I can just scan the QR with all of the devices I want it installed on. Bypasses the need for adb drivers too.

Comment: Are you able to debug on the devices that installed the .apk via your dropbox?

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but as Mike has pointed out, you loose all the logging/debugging functionality =/

Comment: Actually you dont strictly lose logging functionality. When you later plug in your device via USB you will still see the logs in LogCat. But of course debugging functionality is lost.

Comment: Yes you are unable to step through your code with the debugger. But the log is still kept, you can either plug it in and view the log on the computer, or install one of the 3rd party log reader applications to watch scroll by live on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it's possbile, watch this url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tete.wifiadb